# Android Studio Emulator does not show app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, haxm

I've been programming in android studio for a little while now and recently it's been very messed up. It all started when I changed the theme for my app. The emulator stopped working and I tried uninstalling and reinstalling. Nothing worked and I ended up factory resetting my laptop. I reinstalled android studio and still have the same problem. I've reinstalled HAXM and I've also tried testing on my phone. I run the program and the emulator shows up and it shows the title bar with the name of my app, but no content, just a white screen.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/gMxex9Xq) is a link to the pastebin of the log.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55L65.jpg) is what the app looks like in the design view.

Just take out the picture of the duck and that's what it looks like in the emulator

This used to work perfectly before I changed the theme, but I reset my computer so i'm totally lost. I'm running on an HP Pavillion 15 laptop with a core i5 and 8 gigs ram with integrated graphics.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Thank you for your time

-Kelton

Comment: It seems that there are no problems with android studio or emulator. How did you made app show picture? I mean your code for that. Where do you store that picture?

Comment: I did another wipe of my computer and again instilled android studio and now it seem to be working, but the images were stored in app/res/drawable